# Do i need to do any settings on node.js app running on Google app engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform

Here's the deal, I want to use Google App Engine, because of its easy to use and scalability is important, due to google infra scalability I decided to give it a try over Amazon Web Service, which will take quite some times to learn and deploy. But I have few doubts on using node.js on Google App engine. For example

1) Do i need to do manually clustering on each node.js server or App engine will do it by itself? (To improve each server performance)

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

2) Do i need to care about Load balancing on multiple node.js servers?

3) Do i need to reverse proxy the webserver to so that it could serves the static files even faster? (node.js has been known to poorly serves the static files)

4) How do i run redis on App engine?

5) Do i need to use Channel API or Socket API to make my node.js application to be realtime? (this app has a simple live update, push notifications, chat between users)

6) App Engine is cheaper or EC2 in the long run?

I know I ask alot of questions, but these are the questions that Im struggling to clarify by myself. Hopefully someone with a better experience could explain this to me.

Regards,
Jack Moscovi

Comment: This belongs on Server Fault not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Alright thanks for telling me that.

Comment: Yeah no problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this isn't the right way to ask a question. Please go through FAQs, I am answering this still to help you. But from next time please google your queries first.

**Do i need to do manually clustering on each node.js server or App engine will do it by itself? (To improve each server performance)**

Google's App Engine distribution channel works on its own and hence it has nothing to do with your manual clustering and all.

**Do I need to care about Load balancing on multiple node.js servers?**

Addition and removal of instances is done automatically and over them a tier of load balance mechanism is there, so you need not to worry.

**Do I need to reverse proxy the webserver to so that it could serves the static files even faster? (node.js has been known to poorly serves the static files)**

The choice is yours, for general static content I personally just rely on the file system without any explicit reverse proxy method because hey in the end google's app engine is doing fair bit of that. Run a test with both mechanism and based on results choose what you need to do.

For dynamically loading images, I suggest that you use separate container etc.

**How do I run redis on App engine?**

You don't, app engine is for programming environment why would you want to use it for storage purposes. Use a compute engine and install redis or you can deploy a bitnami or google's infrastructure directly.

**Do i need to use Channel API or Socket API to make my node.js application to be realtime? (this app has a simple live update, push notifications, chat between users)**

This is not related to your cloud architecture. You need to do what is required at your application level. Having said that Socket.io is pretty famous.

**App Engine is cheaper or EC2 in the long run?**

The price distribution is given for both, just compare them.

Comment: Really appreciate that you take your time to answer this question. If possible, could you make the question to bold? easier for future readers to read. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can run your Node.js app in App Engine (Flex) and App Engine takes care of automatically scaling your Node.js app and load balancing as well. I don't think you need to create a cluster or worry about load balancing yourself.

You can run Redis on a Compute Engine instance in Google Cloud. Here's a page that describes how:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/resources/databases/redis